# Uniform not set, despite valid location

Tags: opengl, shader, c++

I try to write a simple triangle mesh renderer with OpenGL.

```
void ShaderProgram::SetUniformMatrix4(std::string name, glm::mat4 matrix)
{
  GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(program_, name.c_str());

  if (location != -1)
  {
     glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &matrix[0][0]);
  }
}
```

Is my uniform related code. I made sure that *glUseProgram(program_)* is called before this method is executed.
Also the *glm::mat4* does indeed contain the correct values and *program_* has a value of 3 so it seems valid.
The location comes out as a 0

Here how I call that method:

```
shader_->BindProgram();
shader_->SetUniformMatrix4("matModel", transformation);

texture_->BindTexture();
mesh_->Draw();
texture_->FreeTexture();

shader_->FreeProgram();
```

Now I have following simple Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal_modelspace;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 textureCoords_modelspace;

uniform mat4 matModel;

layout(std140) uniform Camera{
  mat4 matView;
  mat4 matProjection;
};

out vec2 textureCoords;

void main(){    
  textureCoords = textureCoords_modelspace;
  gl_Position =  matProjection * matView * matModel * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0);
}
```

I see nothing on the screen which is the main error.
When Debugging with Nvidia-NSight I find that all values except the *matModel* are correctly set. The *matModel* contains all zero which seems to be why the model isn't drawn.

Why is the *matModel* always zero, even when I try to set the uniform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that nothing was wrong with the code I posted.
I deleted my complete build and rebuild it, and now it seems to work.
I don't see anything on screen but i think that error is unrelated.

I can see the matrix in the nsight debugger.